# How to hide helper functions when implementing `instance`

Tags: haskell

I have `data RegEx` and I want to implement `instance Show a => Show RegEx a`. Here's my code:

```
showAtom :: Show a => RegEx a -> String
showAtom (Lit x) = show x
showAtom r       = "(" ++ (show r) ++ ")"

instance Show a => Show (RegEx a) where
    show (Lit x)   = show [x]
    show (Opt r)   = (showAtom r) ++ "?"
    show (Alt p q) = (showAtom p) ++ "|" ++ (showAtom q)
    show (Seq p q) = (show p) ++ (show q)
    show (Rep r)   = (showAtom r) ++ "*"
```

The `showAtom` function is just an implementation detail. Is there any way for me to hide it, such that it is visible only withing the `instance` definition? Or better yet, make it visible only within `show`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
instance Show a => Show (RegEx a) where
    show x = show' x
      where
        showAtom :: Show a => RegEx a -> String
        showAtom (Lit x) = show x
        showAtom r       = "(" ++ (show r) ++ ")"

        show' (Lit x)   = show [x]
        show' (Opt r)   = (showAtom r) ++ "?"
        show' (Alt p q) = (showAtom p) ++ "|" ++ (showAtom q)
        show' (Seq p q) = (show p) ++ (show q)
        show' (Rep r)   = (showAtom r) ++ "*"
```

Alternatively, you can just exclude `showAtom` from the module's export list.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't list `showAtom` in the module's [export list](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html#sect5.2).

Comment: This only hides `showAtom` to other modules. If you also want to hide it from the rest of the module itself, Mikhail Glushenkov's answer is certainly the way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `showAtom` local to the module by not exporting it, but that will still make it visible within the entire module - not just the instance or the `show` function.

To make it local to the `show` function, you'd need to use `let` or `where`, but neither of those apply to multiple cases when using pattern matching in the function parameter list. You can make it work by moving the pattern matching into a `case` statement like this:

```
instance Show a => Show (RegEx a) where
    show re =
      let
        showAtom :: Show a => RegEx a -> String
        showAtom (Lit x) = show x
        showAtom r       = "(" ++ (show r) ++ ")"
      in
        case re of
          (Lit x)   -> show [x]
          (Opt r)   -> (showAtom r) ++ "?"
          (Alt p q) -> (showAtom p) ++ "|" ++ (showAtom q)
          (Seq p q) -> (show p) ++ (show q)
          (Rep r)   -> (showAtom r) ++ "*"
```